# Write a function which takes a sentence as an input and output a sorted sentence. (The answer should be valid for any given input.)

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to write a function which takes a sentence as an input and output a sorted sentence, and there are two criterias:

1. Each character of the word should be arranged in alphabetical order.
2. Words should be arranged in ascending order depending on its character count.

**Note: - Word only can have lowercase letters**

Example :

Inputs str = "she lives with him in a small apartment"

Output = "a in ehs him hitw eilsv allms aaemnprtt"

Here is my code.

```
function makeAlphabetSentenceSort(str) {
  if (!str || str.length === 0) return 0;
  var word = str.split(' ');
  for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    word[j] = word[j].split('').sort().join('');
  }
  for (var h = 0; h < word.length - 1; h++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length - h - 1; i++) {
      if (String(word[i]).length > String(word[i + 1]).length) {
        var temp = word[i];
        word[i] = word[i + 1];
        word[i + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return word.join(' ');
}

makeAlphabetSentenceSort("she lives with him in a small apartment");
```

Comment: And what is the problem or issue that you are having with your code?

Comment: The problem is, output should be valid for any given input. Also, I want to know how to work function, when the sentence includes punctuation marks. 

Ex: "Isn't it?"

Comment: Is this the correct output for "Isn't it?" => "it inst"

Comment: Yes sarvagya8. Output is correct. But the problem is it should be valid for any given input.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption that the output should contain only lowercase letters.

Well if you want to use the built-in functions you could also write that as:

```js
function makeAlphabetSentenceSort(str) {
  if (!str) return str;
  const nonCharacters = /[^a-z]/g; // to replace any thing other than letters

  // We split the sentence to words by any whitespace first
  return str.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/).map(word => {
    // Here we remove all non-characters from the word
    // And sort the remaining characters alphabetically
    return word.replace(nonCharacters, '').split('').sort().join('');
    // It might be that the sentence looks like:
    // "Hey! ???"
    // In that case the "word" ??? would become just an empty string
    // since all the non-characters have been removed.
    // But then you would end up with a result:
    // " ehy"
    // because the empty word would still get added to the beginning of the sentence
    // Because of that we need to filter the empty words out
    // And to do that I use this lil trick of mine, using "Boolean"
    // as a filter function since Boolean('') is false
    // and Boolean('any word') is true
  }).filter(Boolean).sort((a, b) => {
    // Here we sort all the words by their length
    return a.length - b.length;
  }).join(' ');
}

console.log(makeAlphabetSentenceSort("Isn't it?"));
console.log(makeAlphabetSentenceSort("she lives with him in a small apartment"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, it is not complete my third requirement. => The answer should be valid for any given input.

Comment: Could you please provide some examples of input for which you can't seem to make it work?

Comment: Ex = > "Isn't it?". I want to know about is this function works when there are punctuation marks.

Comment: I updated the answer to handle such situations (and even more! :) ) check it out

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer :) I tested the function when there are punctuation marks in the sentences. I received the correct output. But the problem is my 3rd requirement is not fulfill.  => The answer should be valid for any given input.  Can u help me to find that issue.

Comment: Hmm sorry if I am not getting something obvious, what do you mean by "valid"? Are you running some sort of unit tests that need to pass? I am sure we are very close to the solution! :)

Comment: Your function is correct Ján Jakub Naništa. Even I have no idea what is meaning of the "Valid". That's why I'm getting stuck here. My function is also correct. But, there is something missing part. Yes, I test the function with 3 requirements. 1 and 2 are fulfill. But 3rd is getting wrong.